# Android Client login to a Django server, how to pass crsf :|

Tags: android, django

I'm building an Android Client application to connect to a Django server.
The problem here is I can't login to my server :(. what's wrong, help me :|
Here are my loginFunction():

1. Create an DefaultHttpClient:

   ```
   DefaultHttpClient httpClientStatic = new DefaultHttpClient();
   ```
2. Function to Get crsf from server:

   ```
   public String getCsrfFromUrl(String url) {
       HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClientStatic.execute(httpGet);
       HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
       is = httpEntity.getContent();
       List<Cookie> cookies = httpClientStatic.getCookieStore().getCookies();
       if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
           Log.e("COOKIES GET ",  "Empty Cookies");
       } else {
           for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
               Log.e("COOKIES GET ",  cookies.get(i).getName()+"--"+cookies.get(i).getValue());
           }
       }
       return cookies.get(0).getValue();
   }
   ```
3. Function to Post username, pass, crsf to server:

   ```
   public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

       // Making HTTP GET request to get csrfmiddlewaretoken:
       try {
           HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
           httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
           Log.e("JSON", "In login user 02.4");
           HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClientStatic.execute(httpPost);
           HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
           is = httpEntity.getContent();
           .....
           //Next is read respone, and return json type
       }
   ```
4. Login Function:

   ```
   public JSONObject loginUser(String username, String password){
       // Building Parameters

       List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
       csrfmiddlewaretoken = new JSONParser().getCsrfFromUrl(loginURL);
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrfmiddlewaretoken));
       JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
       return json;
   }
   ```

It still return 401 error anh 500 status :|.

Comment: should you be passing the csrf? is your android being authenticated by sessions?  If you are creating an api, perhaps you should look at a different authentication scheme?

Comment: You can use the @csrf_exempt decorator, since an android app is certainly cross domain, so you should not be using the csrf at all. Best practice though seems to be using Oauth (or Oauth2 actually) instead of cookie based sessions.