# Django CSRFTOKEN and problems with android client

Tags: android, django, csrf

I tried and search a lot of answers here and in others webpages but I spend all day and still can't do it.

A friend build a django backend and he ask me to build an android app to connect to that backend, the best result was this [Android Client login to a Django server, how to pass crsf :|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177827/android-client-login-to-a-django-server-how-to-pass-crsf) but I can't get it work, I get the CSRF from the server but then I try to use a URLConnection, HttpClient, HttpPost, a lot of another examples and nothing.

Right now my code is:

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://URL-TO-SERVER/");
        String CSRFTOKEN =  getCsrfFromUrl("http://URL-TO-SERVER/");

            // Add your data
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", mEmail));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("csrfmiddlewaretoken", CSRFTOKEN));
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httppost.setHeader("X-CSRFToken", CSRFTOKEN);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final BasicCookieStore cookieStore =  new BasicCookieStore();
        BasicClientCookie csrf_cookie = new BasicClientCookie("X-CSRFToken", CSRFTOKEN);
        csrf_cookie.setDomain("URL-SERVER");
        cookieStore.addCookie(csrf_cookie);
        // Create local HTTP context - to store cookies
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            Log.e(TAG,"Token: "+CSRFTOKEN);

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(response.getAllHeaders());

        try {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and the getCsrfFromUrl() is from the link. And in

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("csrfmiddlewaretoken", CSRFTOKEN));
```

I tried to change the key for csrftoken, for X-CSRFToken and I still don't know what is wrong or how can I get it work, maybe is a problem in the backend? A function or key is missing?
What I try to do is login in a page where I need to put the username and the password and then recollect the response to see who enter and work with that data.

Comment: The `getCsrfFromUrl` function from the other question does not work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660848/android-with-django-how-to-keep-user-logged-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getCsrfFromUrl` that you use is buggy, it returns the first cookie found in the response without checking if it is the CSRF cookie, this one should work:

```
public String getCsrfFromUrl(String url) {
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClientStatic.execute(httpGet);
  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

  List<Cookie> cookies = httpClientStatic.getCookieStore().getCookies();

  for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    if (cookie.getName().equals("csrftoken")) {
      return cookie.getValue();
    }
  }
  return null;  // Or throw exception.
}
```

You can then use the returned value as a POST parameter.

Though, as mentioned in the comments of the question you linked, you should not need CSRF protection for views accessed by your Android app.